# Freezing the value of a string variable from outside of a library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using a npm package and I want to customize its behavior by setting a string variable, declared as a string in the npm package's file which is in "use strict" mode.
I would like to know if it's possible to freeze the value of the string variable outside the scope of the library, so that it will not use the definition of the variable in the package without throwing an error. 
My aim is to achieve the customization without the need to change the library file and commit it to svn, which will be totally wrong.

I want to do this:

In **index.js**:

```
const REQUIRED_FIELD_SYMBOL = "";
```

If it's a `const`, I'll get an error because of the re-declaring.

In **Field.js** (a library's file) :
`"use strict";
 var REQUIRED_FIELD_SYMBOL = "*";`

I want it to be shadowed.

Comment: `const` cannot be overwritten.

Comment: @PHPglue that's right

Comment: Even if you save it as `var` or `let` I doubt it will work, because the library will just re-declare it for it's scope, or overwrite it if it's global. Maybe try another way of doing it? Do you just want to remove the * symbol? Where is it used? Can't you remove it any other way?

Comment: I'm not clear with what you want to achieve. There is a variable in a npm library which you want to override?

Comment: @RaulRene I use ReactJS and I don't want to commit the file from the library in the repository. This is the simple way to do it just remove the symbol for a local usage it's OK.

Comment: @AbhinavJain, yes, this is exactly what I want but I don't want to modify the library file to achieve it.

Comment: @elenaHristova Yes but if the library does not offer the possibility to override it you won't be able to. So that's why I'm asking what the end result must be, maybe there's another way of doing it (for example if the * renders in the UI you can hide it by CSS, etc)

Comment: Where are you using the variable and how are you accessing it?

Comment: @elenaHristova What npm package are you using ? there can be a better way to solve this!

Comment: I use "react-jsonSchema-form". [https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/fields/SchemaField.js](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/fields/SchemaField.js) on line 14